# How do you make chrome run faster without removing extensions?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

My school puts a bunch of extensions on my school email and doesn't let me turn any of them off. The extensions make chrome super laggy and make typing a nightmare. Is there any way I can make chrome run faster without turning off the extensions?

I try cancelling the extensions' tasks in chrome's task manager and it stops the lag for like a minute until the extensions' tasks come back and lag chrome again.

Answer (score 1):

**If** you're allowed to, open Chrome in [Incognito Mode](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform=Desktop) to [disable *all* extensions](https://nordvpn.com/blog/chrome-safe-mode/):

- At the top right, click **⋮** and select *New Incognito Window*.
- Alternatively, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>

If not, then talk to school IT.